How to get a list of controller class names instead of class objects in Express with routing-controllers?
I'm using the routing-controllers package with Express to load controllers dynamically from files in my project.
My app.ts :
import "reflect-metadata";


import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { useExpressServer } from 'routing-controllers';
import {  connectDB } from './config/db';
import requireAll from 'require-all';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';



dotenv.config();
// Create an instance of an Express app
const app = express();

// Get __filename
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

// Get __dirname
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const controllers = Object.values(
  requireAll({
    dirname: path.join(__dirname, 'controllers'),
    filter: /(.+\.controller)\.(ts|js)$/,   // Match both .ts and .js files
  })
).map((controllerModule: any) =>
  Object.values(controllerModule).map((controller: any) => controller.default || controller)
).flat();

useExpressServer(app, {
  controllers,
});

// Connect to the database and start the server
const port =  3000;

connectDB().then(() => {
  console.log("controllers", controllers);
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Successfully running on ", `${port}`);
  });
});

When I log the controllers array, it outputs class references like:
[[class Demo1Controller], [class Demo2Controller]]

However, I want to extract just the class names like this:
[Demo1Controller, Demo2Controller]

How can I modify my code to get only the class names of the controllers instead of the entire class objects?
What I Tried:
I attempted using map() and flatMap() to extract the names from the class objects, but neither approach worked as expected.
My Environment :
Nodejs version 20.12.2 and npm version 9.9.4

You can map the classes to their names by applying .name on each one, e.g., with a map call:
const controllerNames = controllers.map(c => c.name);

